# Ubuntu doesnt play any online video sites such as youtube, spotify

Tags: 14.04, video, suspend, flash

Whenever i click 'Suspend' and my laptop sleeps, upon reboot, all online streaming sites such as youtube, spotify, videos can load but will not play.

What can be the issue?

Pls suggest solutions. I have trid almost all the solutions i have seen here. everything to do from removing flashplugin installer, adding adobe flash plugin, reinstalling ubuntu restricted services etc but all to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are the system BIOS is not liking the way Ubuntu is running on your system.  You might need to make a `grub` modification to make Suspend/Sleep/Hibernate work properly with the BIOS.  The idea would be to make it think that it is a Windows system.  To do this, you need to modify the `grub` default file.  Open a terminal window and type in:

`sudo nano /etc/default/grub`

then modify the line reading `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` to

`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash acpi_osi=Windows"`

save the file by pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd> to write the file, then <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to exit the file.  Then from the terminal window again, type in:

`sudo update-grub`

to update the grub.  Then reboot your system.

Hope this helps!